# Why c struct padding is required at __last__ element

Tags: c, struct, alignment, padding

I am aware of padding, and its rules, why it requires etc.

My question is given struct,

```
struct my_struct {
   int a;
   char c;
};
```

In this case start address of c is word align, but still compiler added 3 bytes (assuming 4 as word size) padding. with no element after c and why we need these 3 bytes?
I checked following,

```
int g_int1;
struct my_struct st;
int g_int2;
```

by above what I mean is my rest of variable declarations are not dependent on word align-ness of previous variable size. compiler always try to align next variable irrespective of its global or local auto var.

I cant see any reason with endian-ness since this is char and for one byte it don't matters. what reason I think is instead of checking last element condition compiler *always* add padding whenever required.

what can the valid reason?

Comment: Incidentally, the fact that a structure ends at the exact location it does cannot affect the placement of any earlier elements, since two structures that start with identical field declarations are required to be stored identically up the first point where the field declarations first differ.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because if `sizeof(my_struct)` was 5 rather than 8, then if you did this:

```
my_struct array[2];
```

then `array[0]` would be word-aligned, but `array[1]` would not be.  (Recall that array lookup is done by adding multiples of `sizeof(array[0])` to the address of the first element.)

Answer (score 6):

Imagine you have an array of `struct my_struct`. How would its elements be word-aligned if they aren't a multiple of words in size each?

Answer (score 1):

It's to have the object size also aligned. Imagine having an array of my_structs. In this case you need to align the start adress of every element. Therefore sizeof(struct my_struct) must be "aligned". Otherwise you are not able to tell how much memory you need to allocate.